# list.remove() method not providing expected results

Tags: python, list

In attempting to remove all filenames not starting with a particular substring from a list, I've run into the following unexpected behavior:

```
>>> allfiles = os.listdir(mydir)
>>> allfiles
['dwcpybyext.sh', 'dwlaunch', 'libupdate.sh', 'ntpsync.sh']
>>> for f in allfiles:
...    if f.startswith('n') == False:
...        allfiles.remove(f)
...
>>> allfiles
['dwlaunch', 'ntpsync.sh']
```

This theoretically should have removed **every** filename not starting with `'n'` from the list. Instead, it's left one starting with `'d'` in the list. If I change the loop to use `if f.startswith('d') == False:` I get `['dwcpybyext.sh', 'dwlaunch', 'ntpsync.sh']` -- the last item doesn't even contain a `'d'` character.

*Why am I seeing this behavior?* It seems unlikely to be a bug in Python's `list.remove()` method -- I get the same behavior if I substitute `del allfiles[allfiles.index(f)]`, and `.remove()` is basically just an alias for that anyway.

Comment: Read the note in section 7.3: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a really bad idea to modify list while iterating it.  Try the next:

```
allfiles = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('n'), allfiles)
```

Comment: I'd use list comprehension, which is clearer, and does return a list in Python 3. `[x for x in allfiles if x.startswith('n')]`

Comment: @KennyTM This choise is up to OP

Comment: The list comprehension is a better method for my needs. Thanks for the help here!

Comment: This is beautiful as well, so +1, I was just curious so did a small performance comparison. It seems list comprehensions are faster. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not alter the list you're iterating over. Use

```
allfiles = [f for f in allfiles if f.startswith('n')]
```

instead.

**Update**: Small performance comparison with the `filter` alternative by @RomanBodnarchuk (which is totally fine, of course):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(10000)' '[x for x in L if x < 100]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 662 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'L=range(10000)' 'filter(lambda x: x < 100, L)'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.06 msec per loop
```

It seems list comprehensions are faster than `filter` with `lambda` by a factor of 3.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. In this case speed *is* important, so that's another reason to use the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly, but probably has to do with the fact that you're modifying the list you're iterating over! Don't do that. Instead, use code like this:

```
allfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(mydir) if f.startswith('n')
```

or, if you prefer a loop:

```
allfiles = []
for f in os.listdir(mydir):
    if f.startswith('n'):
        allfiles.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the same list you're iterating.

You must either copy the list or iterate it in reverse order and using indexes to access the list, so that the previous index always exist

```
example = ['a','b','c']
for i in reversed(range(len(example))):
    if example[i] == 'b':
        del(example[i])
```